# Loop iteration through character instead of word when trying to remove stop words from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I'm trying to remove stop words from strings stored in a pandas DataFrame, but for some reason instead of iterating through the words of the strings I'm iterating through every character, which gives me an unwanted result. I was not able to find any solution to this problem.

Can someone please explain why am I iterating through the characters instead of the words in the phrase?

I present the code I am using and the results I am getting bellow. The stop words and strings are in Portuguese but I don't think it influences the results.

```
#List of stop words
stp = set(stopwords.words('portuguese') + list(punctuation))

print(stp)

trainData = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['text', 'response'])

corpus = []

with open('pred.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    corpus += [strip_multiple_whitespaces(line) for line in f_input]

corpus_1 = [strip_non_alphanum(line) for line in corpus]
corpus_2 = [line.rstrip() for line in corpus_1]

train_data = [line.split(' ') for line in corpus_2]

for line in train_data:
    if(line[0] == ''):
        train_data.remove(line)

tmp = pd.DataFrame({'text':train_data[::2], 'response':train_data[1::2]})

trainData = trainData.append(tmp[['text', 'response']], ignore_index=True)

trainData['text'] = trainData['text'].astype(str).str.lower()

print(trainData)

trainData['text'] = trainData['text'].apply(lambda x: [word for word in x if word not in stp])

print(trainData)
```

This is the result of printing the stop words:

```
{'com', 'meu', 'fora', '/', ',', 'aos', 'tu', 'estiver', 'esteve', 'fossem', 'e', 'seu', 'já', '|', 'minha', 'te', 'foi', 'há', 'dos', 'ele', 'fôramos', 'tuas', '[', 'foram', 'para', 'quando', 'for', 'tua', 'estávamos', 'eles', 'sou', 'tiveram', 'estivemos', 'também', 'aquela', 'você', 'tenho', 'às', 'houvera', '-', 'éramos', 'mais', 'houveríamos', '^', '`', '@', 'delas', 'estivéramos', 'nas', 'dele', 'esteja', 'hajamos','hei', 'ela', 'se', ':', 'por', 'na', 'estiverem', 'houveria', 'pelos', 'estivessem', 'tenhamos', 'nos', 'até', 'nós', 'estão', 'tenha', 'teremos', 'nem', 'teu', 'ou', 'estejam', 'fomos', 'sejam', 'forem', 'estive', 'houverei', 'me', '*', 'uma', 'meus', 'houvemos', 'o', 'vocês', 'aquilo', 'não', '%', "'", 'ao', 'minhas', 'tinham', '+', 'do', 'aquele', 'sua', 'hajam', 'sejamos', 'a', 'este', 'num', 'era', 'terá', 'serão', 'tivesse', '=', 'houver', 'esse', 'tiverem', 'um', 'mas', 'nossa', 'está', 'houvéssemos', 'serei', 'houverão', 'estivermos', '?', '~', 'teus', 'fôssemos', 'havemos', 'deles', 'dela', 'tivéssemos', 'tivemos', 'depois', '{', 'nossos', 'nossas', 'estivera', 'seria', ')', 'houvéramos', 'seriam', 'formos', 'estas', 'tinha', 'estejamos', 'tivessem', 'eram', 'será', 'fosse', 'estes', 'teria', 'esta', 'estou', 'pelas', 'houveremos', 'tem', 'houveram', 'estamos', 'lhes', 'estivesse', 'tive', 'numa', 'seja', 'tiver', 'que', '$', 'estavam', '<', 'terei', 'houverá', 'seríamos', '>', 'teríamos', 'pela', 'isto', 'à', 'as', 'esses', ';', 'essas','teve', 'suas', 'de', 'em', 'qual', 'houveriam', '#', 'das', '.', '(', 'hão', 'são', 'mesmo', 'sem', 'vos', 'houve', 'lhe', 'houvermos', 'só', 'houvesse', 'seremos', '\\', '}', 'somos', 'como', 'aqueles', 'estiveram', 'temos', 'da', 'tivéramos', 'eu', '"', 'muito', '_', 'nosso', 'pelo', 'no', 'estava', ']', 'tém', 'estivéssemos', 'isso', '&', '!', 'haja', 'tenham', 'elas', 'tivermos', 'terão', 'quem', 'tínhamos', 'teriam', 'os', 'houverem', 'fui', 'tivera', 'aquelas', 'entre', 'seus', 'essa', 'houvessem'}
```

This is my Dataframe before removing the stop words:

```
                                                 text        response
0                               ['o', 'que', 'causa']    [causadorDe]
1       ['o', 'que', 'leva', 'á', 'existência', 'de']    [causadorDe]
2                    ['porquê', 'é', 'que', 'existe']    [causadorDe]
3   ['o', 'que', 'é', 'que', 'esta', 'contido', 'no']     [contidoEm]
4   ['o', 'que', 'é', 'que', 'esta', 'contido', 'na']     [contidoEm]
5                ['qual', 'é', 'o', 'antónimo', 'de']   [antonimoNDe]
6               ['qual', 'é', 'o', 'contrário', 'de']   [antonimoNDe]
7              ['o', 'que', 'é', 'o', 'oposto', 'de']   [antonimoNDe]
8            ['qual', 'é', 'a', 'consequência', 'de']  [finalidadeDe]
9               ['qual', 'é', 'o', 'resultado', 'de']  [finalidadeDe]
10                      ['o', 'que', 'resulta', 'de']  [finalidadeDe]
11                     ['o', 'que', 'usaria', 'para']  [finalidadeDe]
12       ['o', 'que', 'pode', 'ser', 'usado', 'para']  [finalidadeDe]
13                 ['qual', 'é', 'a', 'origem', 'de']  [originarioDe]
14                         ['de', 'onde', 'vem', 'o']  [originarioDe]
15               ['de', 'onde', 'é', 'derivado', 'o']  [originarioDe]
16                 ['qual', 'é', 'a', 'origem', 'de']  [originarioDe]
17                         ['de', 'onde', 'vem', 'a']  [originarioDe]
18               ['de', 'onde', 'é', 'derivada', 'a']  [originarioDe]
19                     ['para', 'que', 'serve', 'um']     [servePara]
20                    ['para', 'que', 'usaria', 'um']     [servePara]
21       ['qual', 'é', 'a', 'finalidade', 'de', 'um']     [servePara]
22                    ['para', 'que', 'serve', 'uma']     [servePara]
23                   ['para', 'que', 'usaria', 'uma']     [servePara]
24      ['qual', 'é', 'a', 'finalidade', 'de', 'uma']     [servePara]
```

And this is the result after trying to remove those stop words:

```
                                                 text        response
0                               [ , q, u,  , c, u, s]    [causadorDe]
1   [ , q, u,  , l, v,  , á,  , x, i, s, t, ê, n, ...    [causadorDe]
2       [p, r, q, u, ê,  , é,  , q, u,  , x, i, s, t]    [causadorDe]
3   [ , q, u,  , é,  , q, u,  , s, t,  , c, n, t, ...     [contidoEm]
4   [ , q, u,  , é,  , q, u,  , s, t,  , c, n, t, ...     [contidoEm]
5       [q, u, l,  , é,  ,  , n, t, ó, n, i, m,  , d]   [antonimoNDe]
6    [q, u, l,  , é,  ,  , c, n, t, r, á, r, i,  , d]   [antonimoNDe]
7                [ , q, u,  , é,  ,  , p, s, t,  , d]   [antonimoNDe]
8   [q, u, l,  , é,  ,  , c, n, s, q, u, ê, n, c, ...  [finalidadeDe]
9       [q, u, l,  , é,  ,  , r, s, u, l, t, d,  , d]  [finalidadeDe]
10                  [ , q, u,  , r, s, u, l, t,  , d]  [finalidadeDe]
11                  [ , q, u,  , u, s, r, i,  , p, r]  [finalidadeDe]
12   [ , q, u,  , p, d,  , s, r,  , u, s, d,  , p, r]  [finalidadeDe]
13            [q, u, l,  , é,  ,  , r, i, g, m,  , d]  [originarioDe]
14                           [d,  , n, d,  , v, m,  ]  [originarioDe]
15            [d,  , n, d,  , é,  , d, r, i, v, d,  ]  [originarioDe]
16            [q, u, l,  , é,  ,  , r, i, g, m,  , d]  [originarioDe]
17                           [d,  , n, d,  , v, m,  ]  [originarioDe]
18            [d,  , n, d,  , é,  , d, r, i, v, d,  ]  [originarioDe]
19               [p, r,  , q, u,  , s, r, v,  , u, m]     [servePara]
20            [p, r,  , q, u,  , u, s, r, i,  , u, m]     [servePara]
21  [q, u, l,  , é,  ,  , f, i, n, l, i, d, d,  , ...     [servePara]
22               [p, r,  , q, u,  , s, r, v,  , u, m]     [servePara]
23            [p, r,  , q, u,  , u, s, r, i,  , u, m]     [servePara]
24  [q, u, l,  , é,  ,  , f, i, n, l, i, d, d,  , ...     [servePara]
```

Comment: Why aren't you using [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)? And youre iterating on a string, that generates characters. Add `x.split()` to the list comprehension lambda if you want words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first it seemed that I couldn't reproduce... Copying raw data from your example:

```
>>> trainData = pd.DataFrame([(['o', 'que', 'causa'], ['causadorDe']), (['o', 'que', 'leva', 'á', 'existência', 'de'], ['causadorDe'])], columns=['text', 'response'])
>>> trainData
                                text      response
0                    [o, que, causa]  [causadorDe]
1  [o, que, leva, á, existência, de]  [causadorDe]
>>> trainData['text'] = trainData['text'].apply(lambda x: [word for word in x if word not in stp])
>>> trainData
                    text      response
0                [causa]  [causadorDe]
1  [leva, á, existência]  [causadorDe]
```

However I see the error. It's this line:

```
>>> trainData['text'] = trainData['text'].astype(str).str.lower()
```

This converts your `text` column from a list to a string. You probably meant to do:

```
>>> trainData['text'] = trainData['text'].apply(lambda x: [word.lower() for word in x])
```